# Phonegap Amazon S3 SDK: The signature does not match

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-s3

I'm using Phonegap to capture and upload a video file to Amazon S3 and Amazon S3 SDK to get a pre-signed url for the request. Capturing and uploading works fine when using PHP server locally, also there is no issues with getting a pre-signed url from Amazon. However when I combine all this stuff: trying to upload the captured video to Amazon using generated pre-signed url I get "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

Here is my method to get pre-signed url and upload to Amazon:

```
uploadFile: function (file) {
    var //path = file.fullPath,
        path = file.localURL,
        name = file.name,
        type = file.type;

    var s3 = new AWS.S3(),
        s3_params = {
        Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
        Key: name,
        Expires: 6000
        //ContentType: type,
        //ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            var ft = new FileTransfer(),
                url = encodeURI(data);
            console.log(data);
            ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                    console.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
                } else {
                    console.log(progressEvent);
                }
            };

            ft.upload(
                path,
                url,
                function(result) {
                    console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                    console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                },
                {
                     httpMethod  : 'PUT',
                     fileName    :  name,
                     mimeType    :  type,
                     chunkedMode :  false,
                     headers: {
                         'Content-Type' :  type,
                         'x-amz-acl'    : 'public-read'
                     }
                }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I know there are a lot of questions / answers on SO related to this subject, but nothing seems work for me...

Please see the full test app here: 
https://github.com/terreb/Phonegap-Media-Capture-S3-Upload

Please advise!

Comment: I hope you are not embedding your AWS credentials in your app.  That's not safe, but not really related.  Why are `ContentType` and `ACL` commented out?  You can't include then in the request and exclude them from the signing process.  Also, you don't "get" a signed URL "from Amazon."  That's generated locally by your code and will be as incorrect as you make it, if the parameters don't match the request you send, precisely.

Comment: The real app gets a pre-signed url from the PHP server. This example is just to isolate the issue, because I get the same error in both cases: when receiving a pre-signed url from the server or generating it in the app. ContentType and ACL are commented out to show that I'm aware of them and already tried that. I know that the problem is most likely with a missing or wrong param, that's what I want to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure, but it might fix the problem.

according to [their documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) you might need to add 'ServerSideEncryption' in your ***s3_params*** to be like this

```
s3_params = {
    Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
    Key: name,
    Expires: 6000
    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
};
```

hope this helps

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I found the problem: getSignedUrl returns ALREADY encoded url.

The corrected method:

```
uploadFile: function (file) {
var path = file.localURL,
    name = file.name,
    type = file.type;

var s3 = new AWS.S3(),
    s3_params = {
    Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
    Key: name,
    Expires: 6000,
    ContentType: type,
    ACL: 'public-read'
};

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            url = data;

        ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
            } else {
                console.log(progressEvent);
            }
        };

        ft.upload(
            path,
            url,
            function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            {
                 httpMethod  : 'PUT',
                 fileName    :  name,
                 mimeType    :  type,
                 chunkedMode :  false,
                 headers: {
                     'Content-Type' :  type,
                     'x-amz-acl'    : 'public-read'
                 }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Hmm, now I have another issue: files uploading works fine on both iOS and Android with the code above, but the files get unreadable when downloaded from Amazon S3. They do show the right size though...